# Microsoft Graph Beta getSchedule API inconsistency subject

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I think there might be a bug in the following API endpoint to get calendar events for different meeting rooms: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/calendar/getSchedule.
I know it is still beta and I see some inconsistency in returned data for meetings:

Testing scenario when the returned data changes: 
Logged in user: **Bogdan C.**

- Add a meeting
- Query the API and see `meeting title` as `subject`
- Add another meeting
- Run again the query and see `username` as `subject` for the first meeting.

As a test scenario:
request body:

```
{
    schedules: ['room1'],
    //..other params
}
```

As a part of the response:

```
{
    "scheduleId": "room1",
    "scheduleItems": [
        {
            // first meeting added
            ...
            "subject": "**Bogdan C.**", // bad
            "location": "Room 1",                 
        },
        {
            ...
            "subject": "**Design meeting**", // good
            "location": "Room 1",
        }
    ]
}
```

Any idea about what might be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to know? I misunderstand what you meaning. Could you please modify the question, such as what do you want to do? and what is the issue?

Comment: thanks for the feedback @kikang. Edited my post and I hope it is easier now to understand

Comment: I have tried this, and it works. could you please check the two subject when you created it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was related to the AddOrganizerToSubject and DeleteSubject calendar processing variables in Outlook, which both default to true.

We fixed them with the following PowerShell commands:

`$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection`

`Import-PSSession $Session`

`Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails RoomMailbox | Set-CalendarProcessing -AddOrganizerToSubject $false -DeleteSubject $false`

Now the meeting subjects appear as expected.