# How to get event subject and content from Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm sending a GET request to `/users/{id}/calendar/calendarView?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}` in order to get events of a user and after that I'm filtering the event subject and content.
What happens is that in the majority of times the subject in the JSON response is just the name of the event organizer and the content is just a blank HTML instead of the values that can be seen in the calendar normally.

I tried finding another fields in the JSON that could provide the correct information but there aren't any.
It looks like some people also had the same problem ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53615999/microsoft-graph-api-fetching-events-returns-funky-subject) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52761445/microsoft-graph-beta-getschedule-api-inconsistency-subject)), but no solution was found or the one given is not what I need.

The following code is what I'm using:

```py
graph_client = OAuth2Session(token=token)

headers = {
  'Prefer' : 'outlook.timezone="America/Manaus"'
}

response = graph_client.get(f'{self.graph_url}/users/{room}/calendar/calendarView?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}',
                                 headers=headers)

print(response.json()['value'])
```

Comment: Perhaps the current user does not have permission to ready the mailbox identified by "room"?

Comment: The current user is actually the application, there is no user logged in. As per the [documentation of the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-calendarview), the permissions needed to access a calendarView with an application are Calendars.Read and Calendars.ReadWrite, and I have both of them.